# Draw a network/graph on world map using basemap (python)

Tags: python, network-programming, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a list of hundreds of connected countries:

```
...
Albania ; Austria
Albania ; Azerbaijan
...
```

This gives a graph. I would like to draw lines (straight or curved) between the connected countries on the world map (using basemap / python)?

here is an example of the kind of result I would like to achieve 
http://www.lincomrealestate.com/site/images/WorldMapBig1.jpg

Comment: What is your problem? Where have you got stuck? You need to provide some more information about what you know/don't know and what you need help with. This far we only know what you want to do.

Comment: I just want to know what is the easiest way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be really helpful if you provided more information regarding what you have already tried. I have just posted an answer to a question which addresses what appears to be the subject of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154584/741316

The resulting image of the code in that answer looks like:

[image: example output]

HTH